# Using SQL Functions

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2012

Hello i am trying to create a function in ms sql server that accepts an integer parameter and returns a varchar.  I am however having some trouble implementing this and would really love some help with this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCategory (@CategoryID int)
RETURNS int 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Category varchar(64)

    @Category = (SELECT Category
    FROM Categories
    WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID)

    RETURN @Category
END
```

The code above is what i tried doing already.  I get the following error upon execution:=:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetCategory, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '@Category'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure GetCategory, Line 11
Must declare the scalar variable "@Category".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Column `CategoryID` is a Primary key in your table and you are 100% sure there will be only ONE Category with a particualr CategoryID then your code is safe, but if it isnt a primary key and you can possibly have multiple Categories with same CategoryID then I would suggest using `SELECT TOP 1` in your select statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCategory (@CategoryID int)
RETURNS varchar(64)        --<-- This needs to be the datatype you want to return
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Category varchar(64);

    SELECT @Category =  Category
    FROM  Categories
    WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID

    RETURN @Category;
END
```

**Calling Function**

```
SELECT dbo.GetCategory (1);
```

Comment: Okay thank you that work but i am havin trouble calling the function now, i tried exec dbo.GetCategory(1) and it didn't work, i got "exec dbo.GetCategory(1)"

Comment: see my update how to call this function, EXEC or EXECUTE is used to call a stored Procedure , functions are simply used with SELECT statement.

Comment: Okay thank you that actually makes a lot of sense to me now, i understand it completely :)

Answer (score 1):

You say RETURNS int when actually you return a varchar 64.
Also when asking a question and posting sample code of what doesn't work it helps if you say "what" doesn't work. (what error message you get etc).